# Does the fractional equation $\frac{1}{x-5} +\frac{1}{x+5}=\frac{2x+1}{x^2-25}$ have any solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

We have a partial fraction equation:
$$\frac{1}{x-5} +\frac{1}{x+5}=\frac{2x+1}{x^2-25}$$

I multiplied the equation by the common denominator $(x+5)(x-5)$ and got $0=1$. Is this correct?

Comment: A bit careful: $x \not =\pm 5$.Now you can go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is equivalent to

$$\frac{2x}{x^2-25}=\frac{2x+1}{x^2-25}\iff 2x=2x+1$$

which indeed has not solutions for $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Set $x=\dfrac1y$

Comment: Sorry I don’t get your point! Could you please explain better? Thanks

Comment: $y=?$ and there is actually no finite solution

Comment: In algebra and pre calculs context, once we set x=1/y we are excluding y=0. Sorry but think your argument is very confusing for the OP.

Answer (score -2):

Rearrange the equation as

$$\frac{2x}{x^2-25}-\frac{1}{x-5}-\frac{1}{x+5} 
=\frac{2x+1}{x^2-25}-\frac{2x}{x^2-25}= \frac{1}{x^2-25}=0$$

which leads to the solutions

$$x=\pm \infty$$

Comment: Note that the OP is asking the question in algebra and pre-calculus context. Therefore this kind of solution should be excluded or at least presented as a more advanced way to find solutions.

Comment: I agree with gimusi: pretty sure the OP is not asking for solutions in the extended reals.

Comment: Calculus teaches concept of domains which include infinity and are part of the functions in question.

Comment: I would not consider infinity a valid solution here.